# JQuery changing class of a textbox

Tags: jquery, class, toggle

I want to change the class of an input to myClass2 and backwards by clicking on a link:

```
<a id="search" href=""></a>    
<input type="text" id="txtSearch" class="myClass1">
```

My error is that nothing will be changed. My JQuery looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#search").click(function() {
$("#txtSearch").toggleClass('myClass1 myClass2');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Is the dom ready? How can you click the anchor if it's empty?

Comment: Sorry the anchor isn't empty. I just removed the text. How do I check the dom?

Comment: @user3205343,check out my answer below

Comment: @user3205343 `$(function() { // put jquery here });`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is already working, do you downloaded the jquery plugin?

see this sample [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zkxt6q7c/)

```
$("#search").click(function() {
$("#txtSearch").toggleClass('myClass1 myClass2');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#search").click(function() {
  var txtSearch = $("#txtSearch");
  txtSearch.toggleClass('myClass1');
  txtSearch.toggleClass('myClass2');
});
</script>
```

or:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#search").click(function() {
  var txtSearch = $("#txtSearch");
  txtSearch.removeClass('myClass1');
  txtSearch.addClass('myClass2');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add 'return false'; to your click function. Otherwise the browser will follow the link and refresh the browser.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#search").click(function() {
        $("#txtSearch").toggleClass('myClass1 myClass2');
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be this:

```
$("#search").click(function() {
  $("#txtSearch").toggleClass('myClass2');
});
```

Give only one class name.

**Note: if you will give both class name then this will apply both class property and you cann't find that which class is applying.**

[Read more here](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-className-switch).